# Unable to load user control in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am trying to add `UserControl` on my page using `MVVM` and `Caliburn.micro`.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" x:Name="ActivateItem"></ContentControl>
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel: Conductor<object>
    {
        public MedicalTitleViewModel()
        {
            ActivateItem(new MenuViewModel());
        }
    }
```

but `MenuView.xaml` is not loaded in calling window. No error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContentControl` name should be `ActiveItem` instead of `ActivateItem`. Also, make sure that View and ViewModel are in same namespace.

Comment: By the same namespace, you probably mean "rootNamespace.Views.MainWindowView" and "rootNamespace.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel, right?

Comment: Yes. If it's necessary to keep them in separate namespace then have to use 
 `ExportedView` attribute on viewmodel.